# .NET thread pool and execution context, ExecutionContext class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

There is a statement in Chapter 27, CLR via c# book written by Richter:

> You can use ExecutionContext class to suppress the flowing of an execution context, thereby improving your application performance. The preformance gains can be quite substantial for a server application.

Followed by example:

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("Name", "Jeffrey");

//Initiate some work to be done by thread pool
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
           state => Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", CallContext.LogicalGetData("Name")
));
```

Followed by 2nd part:

```
//Now suppress the flowing of the Main thread's execution context
ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();

//Initiate some work to be done by thread pool
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
           state => Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", CallContext.LogicalGetData("Name")
));

ExecutionContext.RestoreFlow();
```

Result:

```
Name=Jeffrey
Name=
```

The child thread has lost its context (in the 2nd part of example), as a side effect parameters are lost after supressing. But we have saved CPU time (in my case about 10% of CPU time was saved).

- Do you use ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow() method for reducing CPU processing time?
- What other drawbacks except of losing the input args and context may occur?
- How do you recommend to mesure the time execution difference?

Comment: Do not use `RestoreFlow`. Grab the result of `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();` and call [Undo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.asyncflowcontrol.undo(v=vs.110).aspx) on that result to restore the flow (not an answer to your question, just a tip.. it's the microsoft's recommended practice)